# ¿Cómo puedo añadir éste código a mi menú?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, pygame

He empezado a trabajar con Pygame, y utilizando la librería pygame_menu he hecho éste menú en un fichero llamado Menuprincipal.

```
# Importar librerías
import pygame
import pygame_menu

# Iniciar pygame y otras variables
pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Project MatZanfe")

font = pygame_menu.font.FONT_8BIT
font1 = pygame_menu.font.FONT_NEVIS
font2 = pygame_menu.font.FONT_BEBAS

#menu Sumas
menu3 = pygame_menu.Menu('Sumas', 600, 400,
                       theme=pygame_menu.themes.THEME_BLUE)

menu3.add.button('Sumas infinitas', font_name = font1, font_color = 'green')

#menu 2
menu2 = pygame_menu.Menu('Selección del mòdulo', 600, 400,
                       theme=pygame_menu.themes.THEME_SOLARIZED)


menu2.add.button('Sumas',menu3, font_name = font2, font_color = 'green')

#main menu
menu = pygame_menu.Menu('Project MatZanfe', 600, 400,
                       theme=pygame_menu.themes.THEME_SOLARIZED)

user_input = menu.add.text_input('Usuario: ', font_name = font1, font_color = 'blue')
age_input = menu.add.text_input('Edad: ', font_name = font1,font_color = 'Black')
menu.add.button('Empezar', menu2, font_name = font, font_color = 'green')
menu.add.button('Salir', pygame_menu.events.EXIT, font_name = font,font_color = 'red')

# Correr el menú
menu.mainloop(surface)
```

El caso es me sugirieron hacer el nivel de sumas infinitas por separado, en un archivo llamado Suma1. Básicamente lo que hace éste código es generar dos números aleatorios, y los hace aparecer en pantalla además de otras cosas.

```
import pygame
import random
from InputBox import InputBox
from pygame import mixer
import time

pygame.init()

pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1000)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Projecte MatZanfe")
font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 50)
base_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
user_text = ''
color_active = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
running = True
points = 0
t = 60

def TimeFunction():
    t = 60
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        t = t - 1
        return t

def start_the_game():
    x = random.randint(0, 10)
    y = random.randint(0, 10)
    is_correct = False
    return x, y

def display_the_game(x, y):
    # Variables
    surface.fill((255, 70, 90))
    text = font.render(str(x) + "+" + str(y), True, (255, 255, 255))

    text_surface = base_font.render(user_text, True, (255, 255, 255))
    surface.blit(text, (260, 120))
    input_box.draw(surface)
    punts = font.render("Puntuació: " +  str(points),True, (255,255,255))
    surface.blit(punts, (350,30))
    titolsuma = font.render("SUMA (1)", True, (0,0,0))
    surface.blit(titolsuma,(10,20))
    temps = font.render("Temps: " + str(t),True, (255,255,51))
    surface.blit(temps,(0,360))

x, y = start_the_game()
input_box = InputBox(190, 250, 200, 32)

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            t -= 1
            temps = font.render("Temps:" + str(t), True, (255, 255, 51))
            surface.blit(temps, (0, 360))
            pygame.display.flip()
            if t == 0:
                pygame.QUIT
        else:
            result = input_box.handle_event(event)
            if result != None:
                if int(result) == int(x) + int(y):
                    points = points + 5
                    t = t + 5
                  
                # Genera unos nuevos números
                x, y = start_the_game()

                # Crea una nueva caja dónde poner el resultado
                input_box = InputBox(190, 250, 200, 32)


    display_the_game(x, y)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

El problema que tengo consiste en que no sé como transformar el código del nivel de las sumas infinitas para que aparezca al darle al botón de Sumas Infinitas del menú del juego. La InputBox importada la puede encontrar aquí: https://github.com/Maskedllama/InputBox

Comment: Los documentos del pygame_menu se pueden encontrar aquí, auque no he encontrado la respuesta a lo que buscaba. https://pygame-menu.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.3/